# Script to test Active Directory Authentication Time

Tags: vbscript, scripting, active-directory

Simple question: Does anyone know any script (VBS, AutoIT, Batch, whatever displays an output) that could test the Active Directory response time to authentications?

I need to run this as a scheduled task, and get the results from each minute, in order to generate graphics for each AD Server.

I've tried Adtest and some powershell lines, but still couldn't get it to work.

Thanks.

Comment: See if this could be of some use- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19850-01/816-6400-10/authrate.html

Comment: Wireshark generates graphics, but I'm not sure it can be used in the way you are describing. https://www.wireshark.org/